# need to send a certificate to a HTTPS URL

Tags: node.js, rest, express, https, certificate

I am using a third party API which requires me to <strike>send a certificate to a HTTPS URL</strike> send a HTTPS request after signing it using a given certificate from my webserver written in NodeJS express framework.

I am not sure how to go about it as except above description, no documentation is available.

Comment: you can not sign an HTTPS request. You can authenticate with a certificate during the handshake phase of SSL protocol. You need to create a self-signed certificate and provide the public part to the server, or use the given certificate provided by  the third party

Answer (score 0):

That third party may be expecting you to provide a path to certificate either via API .or via a pre configured location.

You can generate a freely available certificate using some Certificate Authority.
like [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/) . You will get priviate key. and a certificate.

Comment: I realized that its wrong to provide path to a certificate. Instead I am supposed to sign the HTTPS request using the certificate.

Comment: Yes by path I mean give path to a local library which deal with HTTPS. may be I mis understood.

Comment: I think letencrypt generates certificates for SSL servers, not for client autenticación. You can use OpenSSL to create self-signed certificates

Comment: In case of needing to generate a self-signed certificates, the public part must be sent to servers to stablish trust